How to deal with an IndexError: list index out of range after using Onnxruntime
I hope someone may help me with my error message. I am running the onnxruntime sess = rt.InferenceSession() and then res = sess run(None, {a dictionary of things I want}). When I print the result, I get an array that looks like this,
[array([[0.86897475, 0.13102525],
   [0.68731904, 0.31268096],
   [0.68731904, 0.31268096],
   ...,
   [0.68731904, 0.31268096],
   [0.86897475, 0.13102525],
   [0.7062882 , 0.29371178]], dtype=float32)]

I want to convert this into a dataframe, so I use the following,
prob = pd.DataFrame(res[1][:,1], columns=['prob_1'])

However, I get an error message: IndexError: list index out of range.
I want to build a dataframe of the second column, and call it prob_1.
I hope the above made sense and would appreciate any help.
Thank you

As far as I can see, the outermost list is basically [array(...)], so it is a list of exactly one element, and so res[1] is out of bounds.

hi @JohnGordon, that's what i thought too, so I did prob = pd.DataFrame(res[:,1], columns=['prob_1']). But I got a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple. Kind of stuck!

res is a plain list, so you can't use [:,1] to index it.

All you need is probably to simply review https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

You just need to do this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

res = [np.array([[0.86897475, 0.13102525],
                 [0.68731904, 0.31268096],
                 [0.68731904, 0.31268096],
                 [0.68731904, 0.31268096],
                 [0.86897475, 0.13102525],
                 [0.7062882 , 0.29371178]], dtype=np.float32)]

prob = pd.DataFrame(res[0][:, 1], columns=['prob_1'])

print(prob)

which gives
     prob_1
0  0.131025
1  0.312681
2  0.312681
3  0.312681
4  0.131025
5  0.293712

